# Erro Autocomplete em campo - Laravel

Tags: laravel, typeahead

Estou com problema ao implementar um campo autocomplete, estou usado `Laravel 5.9` e `Bootstrap Typeahead JS`.

Segue código:

Rota:

```
Route::get('buscarservicos', 'SearchController@searchService')->name('searchService');
```

Controller:

```
public function searchService(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::table('service')
            ->select('des_ser')
            ->where("des_ser","LIKE","%{$request->input('service')}%")
            ->get();
    //retorna uma json para tratar na view
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="service">Serviço</label>
       <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" 
        name="service" id="service">
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('searchService') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
    return process(data);
    });
    }
    });
</script>
```

A busca é realizado, porém ao receber o retorno do controller, o sistema apresentar o seguinte erro:

> bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.displayText(...).toLowerCase is not a function

Alguém alguma ideia do que pode estar causando o problema?

Comment: no retorno tem que ter um layout `[{ id: 1, name: "texto" }, ...]` no caso seu falta normalizar isso.

Comment: Como poderia realizar isso? Consegue me dar um exemplo?

Comment: fiz um exemplo adeque ao seu código!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa de um `layout` de ***retorno*** da seguinte forma:

```
[{id: 1, name: "texto"}, ... ]
```

então no retorno do seu método do `controller` essa alteração no método `select` do `DB`:

```
public function searchService(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::table('service')
            ->select('des_id as id', 'des_ser as name')
            ->where("des_ser","LIKE","%{$request->input('service')}%")
            ->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

sendo assim:

```
'des_id as id', 'des_ser as name'
```

para renomear os campos para o layout (***Observação:*** *eu não sei se tem esse campo `des_id` mera suposição para exemplificar, acredito que essa tabela tenha o campo de identificação, então coloque o nome referente*)

Comment: Virgilio, era isso mesmo. Obrigado!